# Not able to run selected lines in REPL R in sublime text

Tags: r, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Followed these instructions to set up REPL for sublime text
http://www.kevjohnson.org/using-r-in-sublime-text-3/

R console is running. But I am unable to push text to console using the shortcuts
Ctrl+Shift+,,l

I must be doing something wrong here, not able to figure it out on my own. Any help appreciated.

I get the following error:

```
Cannot find REPL for 'regexp'
```

Edit: Adding sample code

```
library("e1071")
data(iris)
m <- naiveBayes(Species ~ ., data = iris)
m
table(predict(m, iris), iris[,5])
```

Comment: Have you tried using the menu items? **`Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Eval in REPL`** or **`-> Transfer to REPL`**

Comment: Yes, still doesn't work

Comment: Can you post some of the code you're working with so I can take a shot? Also, do you have the syntax for your R source code set correctly?

Comment: @MattDMo Not sure if the code has anything to do with the problem, it won't execute anything through selecting text and pushing it. I am able to work directly in the console perfectly. Still adding sample code that i will be running.

Comment: Have you checked the syntax of your file? REPL checks scopes to know what console to run. If your syntax is `regexp` as it seems to be, you need to change it to R (from command panel : `Set syntax : R`

Comment: seems to work now. @scoa didnt have to that. Very confused on why it wasnt working before. Thanks for your help. Could you post your last comment as a suggestion so that i can mark this question as answered.

Comment: @karx maybe you saved the file in between. Sublime changes syntax on save, based on the file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REPL checks scopes to know what console to run, and returns an error if no console is associated to a language. It might have been that your file was not in the R syntax.

To change the syntax : Command Panl (ctrl+shift+p), Set Syntax: R