# Using R in Sublime Text 3: Shortcut

Tags: r, console, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3

I've installed R in Sublime Text 3 on my Windows 8.1 64bit as described here:
http://www.kevjohnson.org/using-r-in-sublime-text-3/

However, I don't know how to push code to the R console.

This same problem is described here, but the suggested solutions don't work for me (Using the menu items/Changing the syntax):
[Not able to run selected lines in REPL R in sublime text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063748/not-able-to-run-selected-lines-in-repl-r-in-sublime-text)

I don't even understand what kind of shortcut Ctrl+Shift+,,l is supposed to be. Pressing Control and Shift down and then entering two commas and an l?

I hope someone can help me answer my very first question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

I hadn't heard of Repl until this post.  I just checked it out.  It turns out the double character means "release".  So "Ctr - shift - comma", release, and then press "L".  Let me know it that helps you run a line in the console.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be an interpretable command indeed. I get an error message now, but I seem to be one step closer and figure out further steps. Thanks!

Comment: I get the error message "Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected trailing characters in Packages\User\SublimeREPL.sublime-settings:6:1.

Secondly, the your suggested command does indeed send my code to the command line, but it doesn't execute.